# Angular ui-grid - Error exporting to excel

Tags: excel, export, ui-grid

When I try to export to excel the following message appears: **Cannot read property 'styles' of null**. I'm following the documentation [ui-grid-docs](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#!/tutorial/206_exporting_data).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApQdx.png)

Answer (score 1):

I am using ui-grid v4.4.11.  This is a bit of a hack, but I found that docDefinition was being set to null at line 20343.  I commented it out and it now works.  See code same of prepareAsExcel function where I commented out docDefinition.

```
        prepareAsExcel: function(grid, workbook, sheet) {
      var docDefinition = {
        styles: {

        }
      };

      if ( grid.options.exporterExcelCustomFormatters ){
        //docDefinition = grid.options.exporterExcelCustomFormatters( grid, workbook, docDefinition );
      }
      if ( grid.options.exporterExcelHeader ) {
        if (angular.isFunction( grid.options.exporterExcelHeader )) {
          grid.options.exporterExcelHeader(grid, workbook, sheet, docDefinition);
        } else {
          var headerText = grid.options.exporterExcelHeader.text;
          var style = grid.options.exporterExcelHeader.style;
          sheet.data.push([{value: headerText, metadata: {style: docDefinition.styles[style].id}}]);
        }
      }

      return docDefinition;
    },
```